# Make Phoenix Controller to output pretty JSON

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there a way to make `Phoenix.Controller.json(conn, data)` to output pretty JSON?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Phoenix.Controller.json/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#json/2) currently does not accept options that could be passed to the JSON encoder.

If you want to globally make all `json` calls output pretty JSON, you can create a wrapper around `Poison` and tell Phoenix to use it.

In `lib/my_app/pretty_poison_encoder_for_phoenix.ex`, add:

```
defmodule MyApp.PrettyPoisonEncoderForPhoenix do
  def encode_to_iodata!(data) do
    Poison.encode_to_iodata!(data, pretty: true)
  end
end
```

And in `config/config.exs`, add:

```
config :phoenix, :format_encoders, json: MyApp.PrettyPoisonEncoderForPhoenix
```

After restarting the server, all your `json` calls should automatically print pretty JSON.

If you only want pretty output in `dev`, you can instead add the above code in `config/dev.exs`. If you do that, `prod` will still output non-pretty JSON.

---

You can also create a simple wrapper that does what `Phoenix.Controller.json/2` does (almost; see note below) but also makes the output pretty:

```
def pretty_json(conn, data) do
  conn
  |> put_resp_header("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
  |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(data, pretty: true))
end
```

Usage:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  pretty_json conn, [%{a: 1, b: 2}, %{c: 3, d: 4}]
end
```

Output:

```
➜ curl localhost:4000
[
  {
    "b": 2,
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "d": 4,
    "c": 3
  }
]
```

Note: This is not exactly equivalent to `Phoenix.Controller.json/2` as that function only adds the content-type if one is not present. You can use the same logic by copying some code from [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2.0/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L743-L756).